# Run Grunt Task With sudo from Webstorm

Tags: node.js, permissions, gruntjs, webstorm

I have a Grunt task that requires extended permissions. 
In the console I would just run the Grunt task with `sudo`, but I'm trying to use Webstorms' built-in Grunt task runner.

Is there such a way to define that a task would run with extended permissions, either in the task definition or in a setting in Webstorm?

Thank you

Comment: I may only suggest to create External Tools entry and run that task this way. Possibly related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11972 -- check comments: maybe you can somehow apply it for your grunt as well (will affect all tasks, obviously).